# Is there a way to get consistent results when replacing zero values with smaller values (ie. 0001) in compana?

Tags: r, adehabitathr

I'm using the `compana` function in `Adehabitat` package to determine if used habitat is selected for from available habitat.

One of the habitat classes I'm using in my available matrix has several very low values (ie. `0.000015000`) or zero values. Therefore, when I replace any zero values in the R code with a larger value (`0.001`), it affects my results. When I replace that larger value with other values (ie. `0.0001` and `0.00000001`), to confirm the consistency of the results, my results are not consistent.

Is there an appropriate small value number I should be using?

---

I've tried using multiple different small values to replace the zero values in the matrix. Smaller numbers than `0.001` do not the top results (working with 9 different habitat classes), but continuously increasing the smaller values changes values of other habitat classes.

```
bars<-compana(used, avail, test = c("randomisation"),
    rnv = 0.01, nrep = 1000, alpha = 0.1)
```

Changing the `rnv` value from `0.01` --> `0.0001` alters results, and continues to alter with smaller numbers

I expect to see consistent results with most or all rnv small number values.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading the paper by Aebischer et. al. (C*ompositional Analysis of Habitat Use From Animal Radio-Tracking Data*, in Ecology, Vol. 74, No. 5 (Jul., 1993), pp. 1313-1325) which the compana function is built on. It is rather easy to read and explains many aspects running compositional analyses for habitat use.

On pages 1320-1321 the authors say the following:

> [...] 0% represents a use too low to be recorded, so should be
> replaced by a value distinctly less than the smallest nonzero value:
> an order of magnitude less is probably appropriate to most situations.

I would therefore check for the smallest nonzero value in your dataset and choose a value of one magnitude less to exchange your zeros.